# default route with dynamic IDs

Tags: angular

Bascially I have a tab and each tab page is a child:

Here is `TabIndexComponent.html`:

```
<tab>
    <tab-page *ngFor="let t of tabs">
        <a routerLink="{{t.id}}">{{t.name}}</a>
    </tab-page>
</tab>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The `tabs` is returned from the server with an `id` field and a `name` field. The `id` field will be used to grab more info for each tab page which will show up in the `router-outlet`.

Here is an excerpt of the routes:

```
{
    path: 'tab',
    component: TabIndexComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            redirectTo: '???',
            pathMatch: 'full'
        },
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: TabComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

My problem is how do I default the tab to the first tab page since I don't know the `id` of the first tab page at compile time. What should I put into the question marks in the above route?

Or some dynamic routing at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The Resolve class is built exactly for this kind of scenarios where you need to load data before rendering component/ activate the route.

More throughout example: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

In your case I would write the resolver service for tabs id, then reference this service in the route meta data. Inside your TabComponent subscribe to the data from route using the ActivatedRoute interface.

Comment: Given the URL `http://localhost:4200/tab/`, how can you tell Angular to go to `http://localhost/tab/3ae348dc`, for example? This is because without setting up the correct redirect, the `TabComponent` won't even be hit.

Comment: First you subcribe to the activated route, if the :id is empty you further subscribe to this.route.data - like in the example - to get the tabIds from your API endpoint, get the first tabId from it and navigate to it using the router service. Something like this:

this.tabId = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
if (!this.tabId) { 

this._route.data.subscribe( data => 
//get the id of the tab u want to dis play then this.router.navigateTo('/tab/3ae348dc'))

}

Comment: Where do you subscribe? In `TabIndexComponent` or `TabComponent`?

Comment: In TabIndexComponent you don't have the id as param yet, right ? so TabComponent

Comment: In `TabIndexComponent` I go to the server to get the tab info to build the tab HTML so I would say I have all the IDs.

Comment: Ah ok, so you just need to navigate to the id you wish for after the tabs data in TabIndexComponent are loaded. If there is never a case where /tab/ gives you some kind of different view then /tab/:id then I would consider use tab-component inside tab-index-component so you have <tab-component></tab-component> instead of <router-outlet></router-outlet> and spare yourself the binding problem. Your Router config would be   path: 'tab/:id',
    component: TabIndexComponent

Answer (score 0):

```
export class DynamicIdGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private dynamicIds: DnamicIdsService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> {

    if(route.children.length > 0) {
        return of(true);
    } else {
        return this.dynamicIds.get()
        .pipe(
          map(ids => {
            this.router.navigate([`/${ids[0]}`]);
            return of(false);
          })
        )
    }
  }
}
```

Not elegant, but does the trick for now.

```
    {
        path: 'tab',
        component: TabIndexComponent,
        canActivate: [DynamicIdGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: TabComponent
            }
        ]
    }
```